# Understanding Size in SQL Server Facet

Tags: sql-server

Right Clicking on a data base and the selecting `Facets`, shows many properties. I am trying to understand these. I am stuck on Size.

What is this?

1. Size of "data file + log file" or only data file or count of page
   files
2. If its size then is it in MB?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the database size in Facets for the database is in MB and it is a combined size of the data and log file for the database.  You may also notice the value also closely matches the size in the properties of the database.